# Linq to sql: Order by datetime desc, then order by the time part of the data asc?

Tags: linq-to-sql

This is a quick one. 
In Linq to sql, I need to order by a datetime field descending then order by the time part of the same datetime filed ascending, make sense? Here's an example of the result needed: 
 
[Serial] [Date (mm-dd-yyyy:hh-MM-ss)] 
1         3-13-2008:10-10-02 
2         3-13-2008:10-12-60 
3         3-12-2008:12-05-55

I tried :

```
return query.OrderByDescending(c=> c.Time).ThenBy(c=> c.Time.TimeOfDay);
```

And also tried:

```
query.OrderByDescending(c => c.Time).ThenBy(c => c.Time.Hour).ThenBy(c=> c.Time.Minute).ThenBy(c=> c.Time.Second);
```

but never seemed to work. 
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Use the `Date` and `TimeOfDay` properties for the sort.

```
return query
   .OrderByDescending(c=> c.Time.Date)
   .ThenBy(c=> c.Time.TimeOfDay);
```

Comment: Aww yeah simultaneous answer again

Answer (score 18):

The Problem is that "Time" contains Date and Time information, thus, already sorting completely. You would have to take the Date Part to sort with first.

```
return query.OrderByDescending(c=> c.Time.Date).ThenBy(c=> c.Time.TimeOfDay);
```

Not tested :)

Answer (score 5):

I think first orderByDescending sorts everything by datetime(date+time), so the following orderbys will become effective only if you have any records with the same timestamp.

Try this

```
query.OrderByDescending(c=> c.Time.Date).ThenBy(c=> c.Time.TimeOfDay)
```

Answer (score 3):

Turn it to ticks will work as well:

```
return query.OrderByDescending(c=> c.Time.Ticks)
```

Comment: Thanks. This is acutally the only answer that worked for me.